# Regarding GPS. Is there a way to locate a phone number using gps? Without installing any apps to their cell phone

Tags: gps

My question is regarding GPS.

Is there a way to locate a phone number using gps? Without installing any apps to their cell phone.

I am interested in both Windows Mobile and iPhone. But please do include generic replies also.

Comment: Voted to close as I lost track of the number of incorrect assumptions. Seriously, if you're not installing apps to a phone, why does it even matter whether the phone runs Windows Mobile? Why does it even matter that it's a phone? Why couldn't I do it with my cat? Really, there's no way to salvage this question.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't.

You see, GPS and phones are two completely disparate technologies - nevermind that there are some multi-function devices (e.g. smartphones) which contain both. There is no generic way to connect one to the other that would work on all devices without custom software (i.e. without installing your app).

That said, you could create an app which checks the GPS location of the device it's on, checks the device's phone number, and reports this pair back to you over some kind of network connection (GPRS, 3G, WiFi, carrier pigeon, what-have-you). You'd need to update the GPS position from time to time as it changes, whereas the phone number tends to stay the same.

You'll need to use some kind of data channel as GPS is an unidirectional broadcast protocol (it's receive-only, there is no way to send a message through it).

Note also that you'll need the user's permission and cooperation in installing the app - firstly, the app won't install by itself as most devices have safeguards preventing automatic installs; and second, installing software without permission could land you in legal trouble (unauthorized access and all that).